# Injecting CSS into an existing form

Tags: css, inject

I have a form that is generated and there are no options to format it, so I'm trying to inject some CSS to lay it out a bit nicer. I have been playing around in a PEN at `[Pete's Pen](https://codepen.io/pzh20/pen/dyZVrgv)` where I've managed to add some section headers, but really want to show form input elements on the same line e,g,
first_name next to last_name
Company_name next to Trading_as
Street_address next to Address2

etc

Is this possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've abandoned this approach as I believe now that CSS Grid is a better option.